# Facebook App connection issue

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, social-networking

I am trying to connect a facebook app but it is displaying error as "Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings."

the domain i am using is https://app.streamlivve.com

I tried all of solutions but nothing happen. here is my settings of FB app page
[image]

[image]

[image]

Can you please guide me to solve this error:
[image]

Comment: When you get the error, can you look in the uri and find the value of the uri parameter "redirect_uri"? Paste that here.

Comment: I somehow doubt that your redirect URI is actually just `https://app.streamlivve.com/`, that is rather unlikely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook announced in Dec 2017 that in March 2018 they would change the settings for Oauth redirects:

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2017/12/18/strict-uri-matching/

In a nutshell, you can only redirect to explicit, precise pre-determined URIs now. Which is annoying if (like me) you want to pass URI parameters back as well...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using Facebook SDK 5.6.2. There was an important fix.

Comment: Welcome to SO! If you are positive that updating the SDK will fix the problem, consider providing some details as to why it would.

Comment: Thanks for both of your reply. Can you please guide me that how can i confirm that app is using Facebook SDK 5.6.2

Answer (score 0):

Since this March (started running a couple of days ago), [strict mode is now enabled by default](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2017/12/18/strict-uri-matching/). This means you now need to have the exact redirect URLs you're using marked as such in the app configuration.

You can see more [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security#strict_mode) about what this entails and how to get on with the change.

Further, you **need** to update your dependency to version 5.6.2, as there's a bug in the previous version that wouldn't work with strict URI matching (yes, the one that is now enabled by default), so the login would break. You can see more about the fix [in the pull request that fixed it](https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk/pull/913). I can confirm that updating to 5.6.2 (PHP) fixed the issue.

To update your version in PHP, it depends on which expression you have in your `composer.json`, but if you have `"facebook/graph-sdk": "^5.6"`, for example, a simple `composer update` will suffice.